# Using PHP + MySQL Left Join to combine results from 2 queries

Tags: php, mysql, left-join, join

Here's where I'm getting stuck. I have two tables that I'm trying to pull information from. One table contains data of interest under the `id`and `post_title` columns, the other contains data under the `post_id`, `meta_key`, and `meta_value` columns.

I have an array of numbers stored in `$in`, by which I can filter the data from both tables.

To return the `id` and `post_title` from the first table is a simple:

```
$query = "SELECT id, post_title FROM wplz_posts WHERE id IN ($in)";
```

This of course returns a name and a unique ID for that name, for example:

```
[id] => 8 
[post_title] => Rustic Wooden Chair
```

I however also want to grab a price associated with the `id` returned above, and a single query to do that would look something like:

```
$query = "SELECT meta_value 
FROM wplz_postmeta 
WHERE post_id IN ($in) AND meta_key = '_price'";
```

My issue is that I'd like to be able to return all of this data to a single array with one query instead of two, that way both the `post_title` and the `meta_value` will correspond to each single number in `$in` (say, 8) which will then allow me to return the query to an array and then loop through that array as needed. I honestly have spent quite a bit of time on this and I think what I am trying to do requires a "LEFT JOIN", but after multiple videos and tutorials I haven't been able to figure out how to make this elusive technique work. Thank you for your help. :)

Comment: Will all of your results have a _price meta key value?  If so, an `INNER JOIN` is best, otherwise a `LEFT JOIN` can work but looks like it would require extra work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to do an `INNER JOIN` that looks like this:

```
$query = "SELECT p.id, p.post_title, pm.meta_value
FROM wplz_posts p
INNER JOIN wplz_postmeta pm ON pm.post_id=p.id
WHERE p.id IN ($in)
AND pm.meta_key = '_price'";
```

You need to join on the `id` and `post_id` keys but also filter the join based on the meta_key value which is _price

Comment: This works, and I will look this over until I figure out the logic behind it... Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

If there is exactly 1 row on each side of the join you're looking for an `INNER JOIN`, not `LEFT JOIN`.

```
SELECT id, post_title,meta_value FROM wplz_posts
INNER JOIN wplz_postmeta
ON wplz_postmeta.post_id=wplz_posts.id
WHERE wplz_posts.id IN ($in)
AND meta_key = '_price'
```

But you can adjust the nature of JOIN if there can be cases where only 1 table has matching records

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that you can use a *left join*. This query will return the joined tables. If there are no rows in the meta table that matches the post, `$array['meta_value]` will be `null`. If there are several rows that match, the `id` and `post_title` will be duplicated.

If you know beforehand that every post has at least one meta value you can use an *inner join* instead.

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.post_title, t2.meta_value
FROM wplz_posts AS t1
LEFT JOIN wplz_postmeta AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.post_id
```